# Bower restore adds too many extra files in ASP.NET Core MVC Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017, bower

I created a asp.net core MVC web App using the default project template. It adds few bower dependencies like: jquery, bootstrap, etc. These dependency are already downloaded at wwwroot\lib.

If I now right click on bower.json and click "Restore packages", I don't expect it to download anything new. But it gets a lot of new files, about 50 or so.
Is that expected?

Screenshots of before and after restore below.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is totally fine for Bower, don't worry, it worked so 3-4 years ago, when I started using it. The main idea that Bower does not download just dist files for Bootstrap or jQuery, but the whole repository from GitHub.

Moreover **Bower** does not provide any option to download only dist files. And it is intentional, you can read [this discussion](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/368).

Some time I used [bower-installer](https://github.com/rquadling/bower-installer) to keep dist files in separate folder, but  eventually I just moved to **npm/yarn + webpack** anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the context about bower and its intentions. I am about to try writing a gulp task that would delete the extra files.